# Defining the boundary conditions of a PDE

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, interpolation

I'm first time use Mathematica and here is my trying of solving equation

```
b = 2.1;
a = 1.5;
g = 1.15;
d = 0.01;
k = 25;
l = 1;
L = 6;

r[t_] := b/a - E^(-a*(t - 1))*(b/a - g);
eqn = D[i[x, t], t] == d*D[i[x, t], {x, 2}] + r[t]*i[x, t]*(1 - i[x, t]/k);
ufun = 
  NDSolve[
    {eqn, i[x, 1] == 0, D[i[x, t], x] == 0 /. x -> l, D[i[x, t], x] == 0 /. x -> L}, 
    i[x, t], {t, 1, 50}, {x, l, L}, 
    Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"];
```

After fixing all errors this code was accepted but did nothing. So, Plot isn't show anything

```
list = 
  Table[Plot[ufun[i[x, t]], {x, 1, 6}, PlotRange -> {0.9, 6.5}], {t, 1, 50, 1}];
ListAnimate[list];
```

I know that I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know, what. So, here are the questions:

1) What's wrong with this code?

2) How can I use cubic spline interpolation to set initial conditions?

I tried this:

```
...
pts = {{1., 6.}, {2., 2.}, {3., 2.1}, {4., 1.}, {5., 0.9}, {6., 0.8}};
f[x_] := BSplineFunction[pts];
...
ufun = NDSolve[{eqn, i[x, 1] == f[x] ...
```

Comment: This `Plot3D[i[x, t] /. ufun, {t, 1, 50}, {x, l, L}]` should plot the solution to your PDE, but that plot looks like it is just zero. This `Table[(i[x, t] /. ufun[[1]]), {x, 1, 6}, {t, 1, 50}]` shows you that your solution is always almost exactly zero. Even if I change your code to `d=20` the result is still just zero. Does that give you any idea where to start looking?

Comment: Thanks, I finally found answer for my first question with your help.
Anybody know something about second question?

Comment: It will be helpful if you write explicitly what initial condition do you need. Presently it is most simple. I assume it should be more complex, right?

Comment: I need to interpolate the initial discrete data (for x=1,2,3,4,5,6) at the moment t=1 for continuous and smooth function that I can set to i[x, 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is necessary to agree on the initial and boundary conditions and use the method BDF and data interpolation, then the solution converges

```
b = 2.1;
a = 1.5;
g = 1.15;
d = 0.01;
k = 25;
l = 1;
L = 6;
pts = {{1., 6.}, {2., 2.}, {3., 2.1}, {4., 1.}, {5., 0.9}, {6., 0.8}};
f = Interpolation[pts, InterpolationOrder -> 2];

r[t_] := b/a - E^(-a*(t - 1))*(b/a - g);
eqn = D[i[x, t], t] == 
   d*D[i[x, t], {x, 2}] + r[t]*i[x, t]*(1 - i[x, t]/k);
ufun = NDSolve[{eqn, i[x, 1] == f[x], 
   D[i[x, t], x] == f'[x] /. x -> l, 
   D[i[x, t], x] == f'[x] /. x -> L}, i[x, t], {t, 1, 10}, {x, l, L}, 
  Method -> "BDF"]
ContourPlot[i[x, t] /. ufun, {x, l, L}, {t, 1, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also, is it possible to use more smooth interpolation, like cubic spline?

Comment: Data is not enough to interpolate a cubic spline. But you can put `f = Interpolation [pts, InterpolationOrder -> 3]`. Solution of the equation will change a little.